# GData youtube video upload missing audio

Tags: iphone, video, upload, youtube, gdata

I am using GData Api to upload video on youtube from ios application.
It successfully uploads the video but audio is missing from that.

I am using .mp4 format of video.
Do any one has a clue?

Thanks

```
-(BOOL) setupWriter{
    NSError *error = nil;
//  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//  NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:documentsDirectory];
//  url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"om.mp4"];


    //  NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"om.mp4"];
    //  [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];


NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/movie.mp4"]];
_videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                            error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(_videoWriter);


    // Add video input
NSDictionary *videoCompressionProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithDouble:128.0*1024.0], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                                       nil ];

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:192], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:144], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               videoCompressionProps, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                               nil];

_videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                        outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];


float   angle = M_PI/2;  //rotate 180°, or 1 π radians
_videoWriterInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);


NSParameterAssert(_videoWriterInput);
_videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;


    // Add the audio input
AudioChannelLayout acl;
bzero( &acl, sizeof(acl));
acl.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Mono;


NSDictionary* audioOutputSettings = nil;          
    // Both type of audio inputs causes output video file to be corrupted.
if( NO ) {
        // should work from iphone 3GS on and from ipod 3rd generation
    audioOutputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC ], AVFormatIDKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 1 ], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0 ], AVSampleRateKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 64000 ], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                           [ NSData dataWithBytes: &acl length: sizeof( acl ) ], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                           nil];
} else {
        // should work on any device requires more space
    audioOutputSettings = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                       
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless ], AVFormatIDKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 16 ], AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0 ], AVSampleRateKey,
                           [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 1 ], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,                                      
                           [ NSData dataWithBytes: &acl length: sizeof( acl ) ], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                           nil ];
} 

_audioWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput 
                      assetWriterInputWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio 
                      outputSettings: audioOutputSettings ] retain];

_audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;




    // add input
[_videoWriter addInput:_videoWriterInput];
[_videoWriter addInput:_audioWriterInput];

return YES;
}
```

this is setup writer I am using to capture audio is something wring in this????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [CamStudio Support Forum](http://camstudio.org/forum/discussion/492/quicktime-pro-finalcut-pro-or-imovie-settings-optimized-for-youtube/p1):

> .MOV / .MP4 / .3GPP files
>
> MOV /MP4 /3GPP files are index based. Simply put, this means that
>   there is an index in the file that tells us the specific location of
>   where in the file the video and audio frames are present. Without the
>   index, it is almost impossible to know where the data for a specific
>   video or audio frame is. This index is contained in what is called a
>   'moov' atom in the file.
>
> Now, if the index is at the beginning of the file, it will enable
>   processing of the video as and when successive bytes of the file are
>   uploaded. On the other hand, if the index is at the end, processing
>   the video cannot begin until the entire upload is complete - since the
>   index is needed to interpret the file.
>
> Hence, for MOV / MP4 / 3gpp files, we prefer the "moov" atom in the
>   beginning of the file - also known as a "fast start"MP4 / MOV file.
>   There are tools available on the web to flatten your MOV file. Usually
>   the video editing/export software will have options to create your
>   files with the moov atom in the beginning rather than the end of your
>   file. If you are using Apple editing tools, then see this article on
>   how to produce a "fast start" MP4/MOV file./p>
>
> Here's a list of some well-known formats that YouTube supports:
>
> WebM files - Vp8 video codec and Vorbis Audio codecs
>
> .MPEG4, 3GPP and MOV files - Typically supporting h264, mpeg4 video
>   codecs, and AAC audio codec
>
> .AVI - Many cameras output this format - typically the video codec is
>   MJPEG and audio is PCM
>
> .MPEGPS - Typically supporting MPEG2 video codec and MP2 audio
>
> .WMV
>
> .FLV - Adobe-FLV1 video codec, MP3 audio

Comment: thanks @ankit I am using same .mp4 format but it only uploads video not audio along with that.... ny clue about it?

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with the GData API the last few days and had no similar Problems. I would suggest you checkout the filetypes supported by Youtube: http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=55744. Can you verify the file you are uploading actually has audio? What does Quicktime say about the Format of your Audio track? Youtube recommends using AAC (as far as I can tell).